# Azure DevOps - turn off notification for everyone for data import

Tags: azure-devops

I am doing a data import of Tasks in Azure Devops.

This will create new Tasks, and on save it emails the Assigned To user.  I'd like to turn off this notificiation, for all, temporarily for the import.

Ideally, I'd like to do this at the Project level, however I only see the setting

> A Work Item is Assigned

at the User level, and at the Organization Level.

I'd rather not do it at the Organization Level as this might impact other Projects.

1. Is there a way to do this at the Project level? Or practically at the User level?
2. If not, will setting it at the Organization level stop this notification for all (override any user level settings)?  The user settings should all be default since most of these users will be newly created.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd rather not do it at the Organization Level as this might impact
> other Projects.

The global notifications will take effect for all projects within the organization by default. We do have notifications at the Project Level, but that **can't** override/affect default notifications at the Organization Level.

**Project Level:**

[image]

As for User Level settings, User Level settings can override the enabled(not disabled) Org Level notifications.

So I don't suggest doing changes at Org Level cause that will impact other Projects. Instead you can disable the notifications at the User Level. Though this rule is enabled for all projects within the Org, you can disable it at User Level(User Profile=>Notifications):

Org Level:

[image]

User Level:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes but we need to disable this temporarily for many users.  Can an admin do this on the users' behalf?

Comment: @user210757 As I know this can only be done by the user himself. Admin can't do this on the users' behalf...

Comment: Re: _"Project Level can't override/affect default notifications at the Organization Level"_ - I've added [a feature request to allow this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1272539/allow-project-notifications-to-disable-subscriptio.html), as I'd argue this is a big design shortcoming, especially that many of the notifications relate to Project-specific events.